# Prove that $\int_{\textbf{a}}^{b}k=\int_{a}^{\textbf{b}}k=k(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Please check my proof this is the first time to prove integration in real analysis after try understand 2 days

$\int_{\textbf{a}}^{b}k$ is lower integral

$\int_{a}^{\textbf{b}}k$ is upper integral (I can't find the way to underline -*-)

if$\int_{\textbf{a}}^{b}k$ then$k Sup L(P,f))$

and $\int_{a}^{\textbf{b}}k$ then $l Inf U(P,f)$

but in this case $\int_{\textbf{a}}^{b}k =\int_{a}^{\textbf{b}}k$

then $kSup L(P,k)=kInfU(P,f)$

that meet the condition of  Riemann integrable

therefore$\int_{\textbf{a}}^{b}k =\int_{a}^{\textbf{b}}k==k(b-a)$

Comment: It's fine with me.

Comment: You can use `\overline{ \int_a^b }` to get $\overline{ \int_a^b }$ and `\underline{ \int_a^b }` to get $\underline{ \int_a^b }$. Also $\sup$ = `\sup` and $\inf$ = `\inf`

Comment: @Winther thank you  ^ ^